Have a widget in a Column that occupies no space and draws over the neighbour widgets
I want to have a Column of widgets with a small icon between the widgets. But this icon shall not take up any space but draw over it's neighbor widgets.
I know I could do it with Stack, but it would be pretty tedious to find the correct position for the icon.
So is it possible to have a widget in a Column/Row that takes no space and is still drawn?

a zero height SizedBox with child OverflowBox maybe?

This draws over the previous widget but not over the next one.

of course i forgot about the drawing order ;-(, so check CompositedTransformTarget / CompositedTransformFollower - for sure they work inside the Stack but maybe they could work in Column too - try it (i mean first in the children list should be target and then follower)
